# Google Apps Synch contacts with global address book in exchange

Tags: exchange, g-suite, google

I'm trying to find a way to sync my clients contacts with their exchange global address book on an ongoing non manual way.  I see methods to do it on a one time basis but I need it to do it nightly.

Does anyone have any resources to accomplish this type of thing...

Or, does anyone know if I can use the LDAP tool just for contacts?  Everything I see has to do with syncing user accounts...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [google-apps-sync](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync) tool which will keep your google account in sync with what you have in outlook.  The LDAP tool is only useful for sync'ing your company's user accounts.  (useful for renaming users, or group memberships)  The contacts are not part of LDAP.  The ldap tool also requires a paid google-apps domain... which if you had... you could pick up the phone and get the info straight from them.  I believe there's also a special API for uploading your global address book(s)... but it's also a paid feature.